# Is there a way, using Reflection that I can pass a type into a method and then have that method find the name of that type in the same way as nameof

Tags: c#

I am calling a method like this:

```
SetResources(
   (nameof(Fonts.ButtonLinkLabelTextFontSize), 15 * Ms),
   (nameof(Fonts.CarouselSubHeadingFontSize), 36)
);

private void SetResources(params (string, object)[] resources)
{
   foreach (var (key, value) in resources)
   {
      Application.Current.Resources[key] = value;
   }
}

public class Fonts
{
    public static string ButtonLinkLabelTextFontSize;
```

Note that in this case I am using a static string but I could also change that to a property if that might help.

Note that the way it's used right now is that I use the name of the property as a placeholder. In the current code it's not set to anything.

Here's what I would like to do, but I am not sure if it's possible:

```
SetResources(
   (Fonts.ButtonLinkLabelTextFontSize, 15 * Ms),
   (Fonts.CarouselSubHeadingFontSize, 36)
);
```

Comment: What is the point of the `static` fields at all? Are you trying to _set_ those property values, or are you just using the name of the field as a placeholder to generate a string literal? If the latter, why don't you just have a `const` value assigned to the string literal you want to use? This question is unclear.

Comment: I am just using the name of the property as a placeholder.  In the current code it's not set to anything.

Comment: 1) Comments are for us to ask for clarification. Please don't post a comment to clarify. Instead, use the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67353463/edit) link and modify your post to clarify it in the ways needed. 2) Please answer the other question, given that you are just using the field as a placeholder, why not just declare a `const` value with the name you want?

Comment: Thanks, I changed the question to add an answer to your comment. If I declare a const then it would mean also setting the value to be the same as the name.  I was trying to avoid doing that if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```cs
public static class Fonts
{
    public static readonly string ButtonLinkLabelTextFontSize =
        nameof(ButtonLinkLabelTextFontSize);
}
```

I know it's the same thing, but it moves the nameof to a different place so the calling code is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but you could use `Expressions`.

```
public class Fonts
{
    public static string ButtonLinkLabelTextFontSize;
    public string X;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PrintName(() => Fonts.ButtonLinkLabelTextFontSize);
    PrintName(() => new Fonts().X);
}

private static void PrintName(Expression<Func<string>> property)
{
    var pb = (MemberExpression)property.Body;
    Console.WriteLine(pb.Member.Name);
}
```